# Android, Share library dependency

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, java-native-interface, libav

1. I am Implementing an application that is using LibAv/ffmpeg on Android
2. I am using JNI to interact with the Native code
3. my 'Shared Lib' is using libswscale.so, libavutil.so, libavformat.so, libavdevice.so, libavcore.so and libavcodec.so.
4. All the 'Shared Libs' are verified to be packed to the same directory on the APK file
5. I am debugging on the device ( no emulator )
6. Runtime.loadLibrary($MY_LIB_NAME) trigger an UnsatisfiedLinkError exception
7. Directly running 'System.loadLibrary("swscale")' also cause an UnsatisfiedLinkError exception

My guess is that libav*.so is dependent on additional libs that should be added to the APK, however, I am not sure how to detect these.
Is there any tool to detect dependent Shared libraries? ( Window ddepends equivalent ) ?

Any help will be appreciated.

~Nadav

Answer (score 0):

You can use objdump tool to list needed shared libraries:

```
<ANDROID_NDK_ROOT>\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-objdump -p libNAME.so | grep NEEDED
```

That's for windows. Change path to objdump tool for your OS.